# Why does "Add-Migration InitMigration" give me an Unable to create object of type error?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have my DbContext and I want to add a migration through the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio but I get following error. Currently I am on .Net 7

```
PM> Add-Migration InitMigration
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create an object of type 'GasContext'.
```

I already looked up on the duplicates. I have a parameterless constructor in my context and my startup project is set correctly. My DbContext and models are in separate projects.

#### Edit

Added the stack trace

```
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly 'Context_Project'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'GasContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'GasContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' while attempting to activate 'Context_Project.GasContext'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to create an object of type 'GasContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

#### Edit 2

Added some code. Some information: I have 3 projects one for my Context, Models and the last for an API. The API project just have the empty created project. My Model and Context project are class libraries which is why I don't have a Program.cs

```
public class GasContext : DbContext
{
    public GasContext(DbContextOptions Options) : base(Options)
    {
    
    }
    public GasContext()
    {
    
    }
    /*
        My DbSets
    */

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptionsBuilder)
    {
            dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=GasPr.db");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        /*
            Some stuff.
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at least showing the code or give the full stack trace if it provides further details

Comment: @jcx200 added the stack trace

Comment: Check if all your NuGet packages are up-to-date, i.e.are compatible with .net 7.0.

Comment: @GertArnold My packages have the newest available version 7 like 7.0.15

Comment: @Burryaga Again a minimal reproducable example can help a lot in this instance to help debug this (at least if the suggestion of making sure your packages are .NET 7 compatible doesn't work). Seeing your DbContext, and your Program.cs / Startup file (if applicable when not using top level statements) can help a lot.

Comment: @jcx200 I added some code and information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the order of your DbContext contructors so the empty constructor is first. This will be the constructor prioritised when running the migration given that no options will be provided when running the command.

```
public class GasContext : DbContext
{
    public GasContext()
    {
    }

    public GasContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    /*
        My DbSets and overrides
    */
}
```